# Logarithmic bar chart in d3 with only one order of magnitude

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating bar chart with extreme variance in the quantities, and I have a button to switch from linear to a logarithmic scale.

What base/domain/range should be used so that each tick doesn't clump into specific orders of magnitude. I'd like a nice one smooth gradation as it compresses the upper values.

Right now my data is `domain([1, 39000000])` and the range is the height of the graph. I could fake it and use `[1,10]` for the domain with `base(10)`, but then the ticks don't match up with the quantities.

```
var log = d3.scale.log()
    .domain([1, 39000000])
    .range([500, 0])
    .base(10);
```

[image: Clumping on a log scale graph]

Using a higher `.base(10)` value really slows the graph down. How do other people handle these types of charts? I'm thinking similar to how Yahoo has [log scales for their charts](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=AAPL%20Interactive#%7B%22useLogScale%22:true,%22range%22:%2210y%22,%22allowChartStacking%22:true%7D) with one nice smooth order of magnitude.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7fg6ktj/3/) as an example.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/w7fg6ktj/4/ (scientific notation) or https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/w7fg6ktj/5/ (normal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I just needed to use a [power scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#power-scales), which is what they are designed for.

```
var log = d3.scale.pow()
    .domain([1, 39000000])
    .range([500, 0])
    .exponent(.2);
```

And if it's helpful, here is a really nice site for calculating the exponent. http://edenhalperin.com/d3-scale-generator/